# Automate the LXD configuration interactive setup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, lxc, containers

I realize `lxd init` has an interactive setup for networking, etc. I'm looking to automate some VM's running LXD and was wondering if there is a nice CLI command that documents this configuration as a command instead of an interactive walkthrough.

Comment: See https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2834